# Dynamic class method name in php

Tags: php, class, design-patterns, graphql, graphql-php

I'm working on a project using [graphql-php](https://github.com/webonyx/graphql-php/). There is [an example](https://github.com/webonyx/graphql-php/tree/master/examples/01-blog/Blog) which suggests creating a class like this:

```
use Project\CategoryType;
use Project\PageType;

class Types {


private static $page;
private static $category;

    public static function page() {
        return self::$page ?: (self::$page = new PageType());
    }

    public static function category() {
        return self::$category ?: (self::$category = new CategoryType());
    }
}
```

Later I can use this class methods like so:

`Types::page()` or `Types::category()`

This works fine. However, I think this is an anti-pattern and could be optimised. As the project grows, the number of similar functions and private class fields grows and this becomes inconvenient. 
Is there any way to refactor the class so I don't have to manually add a function for each type but still call the class methods as I do it now? (`Types::page()`).

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the key.  Thank you so much. Will you please post an answer so I can accept it or should I post the complete solution myself?

Comment: Welcome. happy to hear that it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use __callStatic or __call magic methods. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic

```
public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments)
{
    //$name is your type
}
```